# Haskell code errors - I dont understand what it is asking for

Tags: haskell

First time poster, but this site has helped me alot.

I am trying to learn Haskell.

This is the question i'm asked to answer.

Write a function that takes a list (length >=2) of pairs of length and returns the first component of the second element in the list. So, when provided with [(5,’b’), (1,’c’), (6,’a’)], it will return 1.

I have done this myself.

```
listtwo :: [([a],b)] -> [a]
listtwo [] = []
listtwo [(a,b)] = fst (head (tail [(a,b)]))
```

I am trying to take a list of lists *tuples I believe* and return the 1st element from the 2nd item in the list. I know if you take out the [(a,b)]'s and replace the second [(a,b)] with a list like the one in the question it works fine. But when I try to make this function work for ANY list of tuples. I get errors.

Error I recieve

```
<interactive>:1:27:
No instance for (Num [a0])
arising from the literal `6'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a0])
In the expression: 6
In the expression: (6, 'a')
In the first argument of `listtwo', namely
  `[(5, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (6, 'a')]'
```

So i'm asking if anyone can help me deciver the errors and mabye explain what I am doing wrong (don't give me the answer, cant learn that way).

Appriciate the help, might have more questions if this gets answered. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The pattern `[(a,b)]` matches only those lists containing *one* tuple, so it is no help in extracting the first component of the *second* tuple. In fact, if you feed your function any list of length >= 2, you will find that no pattern matches. However, I suspect you have a type error to deal with first. Can you add any error messages you're receiving to your question?

Comment: There are a few problems in your code, and you haven't posted the specific error message you are having trouble with.

Comment: Edited in the error apoligies thank you for looking :)

Comment: You give `[([a],b)]` as the input type of `listtwo`, which says that the first component of each tuple in your list must have type `[a]` --- list of something. When you use numeric literals 5, 1 and 6 as the first components, ghci tries to interpret them as lists. The `No instance for (Num [a0])` error means that ghci can find no way to interpret a numeric literal as a list, which is understandable.

Comment: Is there a way to upvote you pigworker? Thank you VERY much for the response. I understand this error alot better now!

Comment: Should I continue asking questions here? Or is there a haskell chat room? Or just make another question? My other questions are unrelated to this one... THanks!

Comment: You could always visit #haskell on IRC. (I'm not sure what you need to do to get the privilege to upvote comments.)

Comment: There's no problem with making another question here. Just try not to ask *too* many questions, or they'll fill up the front page. And have a serious attempt at the questions yourself first. You might find that the answers to your first couple of questions resolve some of the other problems you're having!

Comment: Yah Thanks Chris, I have been working through these exercises for 3 days probably 12 hours a day. I'm having a lot of trouble with this language because nothing is being explained in the class room. Its just.. this function does this.. not this is how you build it and why you build it this way and what these letters and brackets are. Attempting to read all I can but when I run into errors like that i'm thrown. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say that you want a function that returns the *first component* of the *second element of the list*. The best way to write this function will be by pattern matching. But first, let's think about its type.

Say you want a list of tuples of `(Int,Char)`. This is written as `[(Int,Char)]`. If you want a list of 2-tuples of arbitrary type, you replace the types `Int` and `Char` with type variables, so you end up with the type `[(a,b)]`.

Your function needs to take something of this type, and return the first component of the second element of the list. All of the first components of the tuples have type `a`, so your return type must be `a` as well. So your function's type signature is

```
f :: [(a,b)] -> a
```

Now, how do we write this function? The best way is to use pattern matching. This is a neat way to extract the components of a data structure without having to use accessors (aka getters, if you come from an object-oriented background). Let's say we have a function `g :: [a] -> a` which returns the third component of a list. You could write

```
g :: [a] -> a
g xs = head (tail (tail xs))
```

but that looks pretty nasty. Another way is to pattern match. A list with three elements `[x,y,z]` can be constructed by doing `x : y : z : []` where `x`, `y` and `z` are all of type `a` (remember that the operator `:` adds items to the front of a list). So we can write:

```
g :: [a] -> a
g (x : y : z : []) = z
```

But there's a problem with this - it only works on lists of length three, because our pattern says "Match a list of three elements with the empty list tacked on the end." Instead, we could use the pattern `x : y : z : rest`, where now `rest` matches the rest of the list:

```
g :: [a] -> a
g (x : y : z : rest) = z
```

where our pattern now says "Match a list of three elements followed by anything else at all." In fact, we can make it simpler. We aren't going to use the values `x`, `y` or `rest` so we can replace them with the Haskell pattern `_` (underscore). This matches anything, and makes us promise that we aren't going to use that value:

```
g :: [a] -> a
g (_ : _ : z : _) = z
```

How can we use this to solve your problem? Well, if you had a list matching the pattern `(w,x) : (y,z) : rest` you would want to return `y`. So you can write:

```
f :: [(a,b)] -> a
f ( (w,x) : (y,z) : rest ) = y
```

which will work fine. However, you don't care about the first pair at all, so you can replace `(w,x)` with `_`. You also don't care about the second element of the second tuple or the rest of the list, so you can replace them with `_` as well, getting:

```
f :: [(a,b)] -> a
f ( _ : (y,_) : _) = y
```

Checking it in ghci:

```
ghci> f [(5,'b'),(1,'c'),(6,'a')]
1
```

So it behaves as you expected it to.

Comment: I am sorry I have absolutely no idea how to read that... If you have a moment to explain what is going on that would be great! But I know for sure my way works if you input the list of tuples into the code... Its when I try to make it work on any list of tuples (ie. call the function in WinGHCI) that I get a problem

Comment: response to the edit.. Yah I have been putting in :t listtwo to see the type and it is not coming out how I think it should look, (which should be like your type). I thought to have the function accept lists you need to have something like [a] as the brackets stand for list and A stands for any type no? Mabye I should re-read types...

Comment: THANK YOU Chris!! Great explanation most appriciated. I understand this now!

Comment: WoW Chris, I wish you were my haskell teacher. That has been more helpful then the 4 classes(3 hours each) i've had with my teacher. You have no idea how much I appriciate your response :)

Comment: "We can use the special Haskell pattern _ which matches anything..." Actually you could use normal variable there, instead of the `[]` and the code would be almost as good as if using `_`. The only difference between `_` and a variable is that `_` means explicitly you won't use its value, that is why `_` is more appropriate in this case.